# Can bootstrap carousel function like what this site did?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was surfing and found this site http://www.rollstudio.co.uk/about/ . Do take a look at their WE GOT THE SKILLS section (and view the source code). I like how they are able to display the list item as it is for desktop viewing and automatically changed to carousel went viewed on smaller devices.

Previously what I did is to have two sets of similar contents, one in list style and one in carousel and used the show and hide function but what they did looks like a better solution.

Anyone has any idea how they do it? Or can you share/direct me to a site that provide the function for it.

Comment: Basically you'd have the carousel only visible in mobile and in all other sizes you'd just use the grid. The site in question is not using Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks Aibrean, I roughly figure it out and going to give it a try. Will post it here once I'm able to make it work.

Comment: Was playing around and found this part 

.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

If I were to change the display to 'block' under screen media query and 'none' under small devices, I could get the effect of rollstudio.co.uk. 

Obviously if I were to use that than other carousel on the site will have problem so need to work further on that. Need to rush other stuff right now and will work on them next week Monday.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the front-end developers at Roll studio.
We've built a custom plugin in order to achieve this effect, since we could not find an existing plugin/library to do this.

The plugin is public (https://github.com/rollstudio/RollCarousel) even if the code is not so clean and maintainable (was not supposed to be public!).

With RollCarousel you can define custom 'grid' based on the user's width (column and row), for example:

```
sizes: {
    '500': {
        grid: [2, 1]
    },
    '700': {
        grid: [2, 2]
    }
}
```

We really appreciate your interest in our site, we're more than happy that we helped you somehow.

Also, if you are interested on how we made the SVG Animation, please checkout this pen (http://codepen.io/luruke/pen/mbnkA)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks guys, I will definitely check it out and see how I can integrate that. But as much as possible, I would like to stay with bootstrap. Nevertheless, I'm sure your sharing will definitely be useful to other members. Well done Luigi and Roll Studio!

Comment: And yes, that SVG Animation is sweet. Something that I need to pick up soon, so will be of help. Again. Thank you!

Btw, love your site and that progress bar on pagination, that is real sweet. Very subtle but when you notice it, you go wow.

Answer (score 0):

***** Solutions Found *****

I've worked on a solutions to this and still using bootstrap default carousel. This is my first time creating a sample on Bootply. So please excuse me if it is not properly done.

http://www.bootply.com/qax9DJbVZt

Hopefully this help. Cheers